# How to use proxy in typescript?

Tags: typescript, proxy, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I want to create a simple telegram robot using typescript with the help of this [repo](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api). I need set a proxy, used following code:

```
const bot = new TelegramBot(config.bot.token, {
    polling: true,
    request: {
        agentClass: Agent,
        agentOptions: {
            socksHost: config.proxy.socksHost,
            socksPort: config.proxy.socksPort,
            // If authorization is needed:
             socksUsername: config.proxy.socksUsername,
             socksPassword: config.proxy.socksPassword
        }
    }
});
```

but got a compile-time error which says:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'socksHost' does not exist in type 'AgentOptions | AgentOptions'
```

I read other related issues but it seems there is a lack of type definitions.
Then used this one:

```
const bot = new TelegramBot(this._token, {
     polling: true,
     request: {
       url: "api.telegram.org",
       proxy: "127.0.0.1:1234",
     },
});
```

When i run it, gives this error...

```
code:"EFATAL"
message:"EFATAL: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL 0.0.4.210:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)"
stack:"RequestError: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL 0.0.4.210:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
```

Can anyone suggest me how to set a proxy with typescript?

Comment: If it is incorrect typing declaration, a suitable way to get around it is to use `@ts-ignore` to ignore the compiler error. Alternatively you can add your own, or provide an upstream fix for it.

Comment: I didn't know we have such a thing. thank you, it saved my day.

Comment: Glad it can help! :D Good luck!